# Unable to clear initial state data from chrome for redux

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-persist, redux-devtools

**store.ts**

```js
import { combineReducers, configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
import { 
    persistReducer, 
    persistStore,
    FLUSH,
    REHYDRATE,
    PAUSE,
    PERSIST,
    PURGE,
    REGISTER 
} from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage"
import userReducer from "./features/userSlice";

const persistConfig = {
    key: "root",
    version: 1,
    storage
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    user: userReducer
})

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: persistedReducer,
    devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production",
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => 
        getDefaultMiddleware({
            serializableCheck: {
                ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
            }
        }) 
})

export const persistor = persistStore(store)

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
```

**main.tsx**

```
const queryClient = new QueryClient()

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
          <App />
        </PersistGate> 
      </Provider> 
    </QueryClientProvider> 
  </BrowserRouter>,
)
```

**slices/userSlice.ts**

```js
import { TLoginUser } from "../../types"
import { PayloadAction, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"

type TInitialState = {
    user: TLoginUser | null 
}

const initialState: TInitialState = {
    user: null 
}

export const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: "user",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        login: (state, action: PayloadAction<TLoginUser>) => {
            state.user = action.payload
        },
        logout: (state) => {
            state.user = null 
        },
        reset: (state) => {
            state.user = null
        }
    }
})

export const { login, logout, reset } = userSlice.actions

export default userSlice.reducer
```

**types/index.ts**

```js
export type TLoginUser = {
    user: {
        userId: string 
        role: string 
    } 
    orders: string[]
    basketItems: string[]
    refreshToken: string 
    accessToken: string 
}
```

[image: Redux store management not working normally]

When I re-run the application and try to reset the redux state, whenever I refresh the page, the initial state data could not be cleared and the state data is from other projects that are incorrect. The picture is showing `currentUser` property that I do not expect it exists as I didn't define its property in the project. May I ask how to have the data cleared when trying to reset the state data?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you mean by "trying to reset the state data"?

Comment: I opened the browser redux tab and pressed reset but whenever refreshing the page the old data still exists and it has problems that detecting other kinds of data from other projects

Comment: What old data? Are you referring to any previous state that was persisted? Can you clarify what you mean by "it has problems that detecting other kinds of data from other projects" means?

Comment: As I defined the data types from the script but the chrome redux has data different from the current project but first would like to reset to the initial state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like you just need to blow away the previous "bad state" value that was persisted that is hydrated into your current app's store when the page reloads.

Open the Chrome dev tools and navigate to the "Application" tab, select your app from "Local storage" under the Storage section, and delete the `"persist:root"` key that you find there and reload the page before the app has a chance to re-persist the current "bad state".

[image]

Ideally only one React app runs per URL, e.g. where each URL gets its own localStorage, but if you are running multiple projects on the same URL with the same persistence key then you might run into issues where each app is just overwriting the same `"persist:root"` localStorage key. If this is the case then give your app a more unique key.

Example:

```js
const persistConfig = {
  key: "my-unique-app-root",
  version: 1,
  storage
}
```

Comment: It works after I deleted from the application tab